# Handling transaction data at ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, design-patterns, transactions, asp.net-web-api, petapoco

I want to build server for Point Of Sales which is going to be on top of Web Api asp.net 
My plan is to have one controller for bills.
For handling bills from web-api post to sql server I am planing to use micro ORM PetaPoco.
One bill is going to be written in database at three tables. 
PetaPoco pushing me to have three "pocos" for-each table one.
I want to write these three pocos to database inside transaction.
How I shod design my controller and classes to looks nice also work nice.

Should I ?

1. Make my controller accept three (3) classes for for parameters, Is this possible at asp.net web api at all ? Can I deserialize from one request three different classes ?
2. Make my controller accept one class, after that on server side from that class make three pocos which is going to be written to Database server ? Can someone post how wold looks like that class which is going to be split at three parts ?
3. Make my controller have three methods for posting separate data (bills-header, bills-payment, bills-articles) one by one ?
   Perhaps it will be so hard in this case to have one transaction for three separate calls?
4. Any other approach ?

Comment: If you post the Web API signature and the structure of the POCO classes, someone could help with the design on the controller class.

Comment: is it tree or three on point 1?

Comment: @Fendy three as number 3, Google drive my crazy whit spelling corrector.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with option 2 - since your web client should be agnostic of the implementation details - i.e. whether you are persisting to one table or 3 tables shouldn't really matter to the client.

The controller or the service method would look like this (obviously the naming is not great - you'll have to modify it according to your domain lingo):

```
    public void AddBill(BillDTO bill)
    {
        //Map the DTO to your entities
        var bill1 = mapper1.Map(bill);
        var bill2 = mapper2.Map(bill);
        var bill3 = mapper3.Map(bill);

        //Open the transaction
        using (var scope = db.Transaction)
        {
            // Do transacted updates here
            db.Save(bill1);
            db.Save(bill2);
            db.Save(bill3);
            // Commit
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read about DTO pattern, it would answer some of your questions:
1. WebAPI supports it.
2. That sounds like DTO, so it is a good solution, as you hide your persistence model from consumer.
3. There's no point to force consumer to make three calls, each call has own 'infrastructure'  cost, so it is better have one infrastructure cost instead of one.

Comment: you can start here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Why-Servicestack It is from competitors of WebApi, so you will shoot two things with one shot - get to know something about DTO and about WebApi alternative :)

Comment: here's original DTO description: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html